# why does including CarrierWave::MiniMagick in my uploader cause my APP_PATH constant to be initialized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I'm switching from Paperclip to CarrierWave, and get the following error when including CarrierWave::MiniMagick in my uploader.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
/Users/me/code/project/bin/rails:6: warning: previous definition of APP_PATH was here
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

This is my uploader class:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_and_pad: [280, 200, :transparent, "Center"]
  end

  version :medium do
    process resize_and_pad: [625, 730, :transparent, "Center"]
  end
end
```

Remove the include, and my app starts like normal. Like, I can tell that CarrierWave is trying to run a separate app (I think?), but I don't know how to configure my rails file to allow it, and cannot see that anyone else has had similar issues. Help?

Comment: There are some likely fixes listed in the discussion at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14115

Comment: Thank you, but it does not. That issue is related to spring. Mine exits instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Issue was caused by needing a migration. My previous migration for Paperclip was made as an attachment, but CarrierWave needed it as a column on the Model.

I ran `rails g migration AddImageToItems image:string` and then `rake db:migrate`.

Worked. Also made sure to remove the migration for Paperclip.